# chrome.webrequest.onbeforerequest.addlistener for Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, webrequest, firefox-addon-webextensions

Google Chrome contains some functionality in its chrome.webrequest API (e.g., 
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html#12a7bf1490a26359eadf10917e37c5b9 )
that can be used to redirect certain URLs to a specified web page. The Chrome extension uses a blocking event listener (chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener) and does a redirect for targeted URLs. How might I do something similar in a FireFox Add-on?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Observer_Notifications#HTTP_requests

Comment: @方觉 Only partially works, it fires by loading files, but subject.cancel() does stop them from loading.

Comment: I can't get even that far with Firefox (50.0.2).  I get `browser.webRequest is undefined` or `chrome.webRequest is undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked for a very long time. I'm not sure if there was solution for this at then. But now we can do such things using [Firefox WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) API.

It is compatible with Chrome in most APIs (though some of them are not supported, or not fully supported).

For this very specific question, Firefox WebExtensions support [webRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest) API, you can use it like the way in Chrome:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(...);
```

> Note: To use `webRequest` API, you must have the `webRequest` permission in your manifest.json.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same request format using `browser` namespace. Below is a sample code for the same. Here `listener` is a callback function.

```
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  listener,             // function
  filter               //  object
)
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(listener)
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.hasListener(listener)
```

You can find more details about this api [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest).

Answer (score -1):

Anything that we can show you will be disabled at an unknown time and would not work for webextensions, due to [Kev Needham's plan for the future of Firefox extensions](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/08/21/the-future-of-developing-firefox-add-ons/) so all that you can do is wait until webextensions are finally supported by Firefox.